# Fine-tuning of the cosmological constant (reference request)

Tags: resource-recommendations, cosmological-constant, fine-tuning

It has been claimed in various places on the internet and in books by non-physicists (i.e. by unqualified people) that if the cosmological constant $\Lambda$ had a value different by so much as $10^{-120}$ then galaxies and carbon atoms could not form, and hence carbon-based life could not exist in the universe.

Is this true?  And if so, do we have a reliable reference by a qualified physicist/cosmologist that could verify the claim?

P.S. In a related question, similar claims have been made about the gravitational constant $G$.  Again, do we have a reference for this by a qualified physicist/cosmologist?

Comment: I don't think this is true.  I would be extremely surprised if this turned out to be true.  I would like to see references for this too!

Comment: "It has been claimed in various places on the internet" what kind of places any reference for us too ?